# Dialog Box Element is showing up as null

Tags: mfc

```
void CMFCSterlingViewAppView::OnActionView()
{   
    CMFCSterlingViewAppDoc* doc = GetDocument();
    // TODO: Add your command handler code here
    if (indexEdit >= 0)
    {

    ViewDialog dlg;

    dlg.m_EditId;

    if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
                {

                }
   }
}


void ViewDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_CONTROL(pDX, IDC_STATIC28, m_EditId);
}
```

dialog box m_EditId shows up as null. Why is it null?

Comment: _dialog box m_EditId shows up as null. Why is it null?_ - When are you checking its value and what do you expect it to be?

Comment: Prior to showing the dialog box, before DoModal function

Comment: I don't see where you are setting a value for EditId.  Are you trying to set it so that it displays in the dialog?  I'm confused at how you are trying to use that variable.

Comment: The value is not the issue...Why is my dialog box element null instead of being an instance of CStatic control?

Comment: It's not sub-classed until OnInitDialog calls DoDataExchange.  The control is not valid until that happens.

Comment: the m_EditId Static control is null even after the DoModal() function gets called. Do I have to instantiate the control in InitDialog?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the call to ddx_control and step into the code. You should be able to tell what's going on with the control.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74463/discussion-between-sly-chandan-and-rrirower).